# expo-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I started studying react native.
I do npm install,
And after that npm start, then I get the error in the picture.
When I press Y he repeatedly asks that I press Y and it has no end.
The first time I heard it all worked I also had problems but the way it was solved. And now I can't solve it

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you install expo-cli globally with administrator priveleges?

npm install -g expo-cli